# Simple jQuery isn't working in cakephp

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp

My simple jQuery dialog isn't working with cakephp.

My default ctp is:

```
<head>
<?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
<title>
    <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>:
    <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
</title>

<?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

    echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');

    echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js');
    echo $this->Html->script('test');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
?></head>
```

That output this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/cake/js/test.js"></script>
```

The test.js already inside the 'js' folder:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

And paginateste.ctp

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p></div>
```

Can someone help me? thanks...

Comment: any errors outputing in the console?  have you tried changing $ -> jQuery?

Comment: Wrap it inside $(document).ready(). I believe it's executing the script and the page isn't finished loading. Or you could put the test.js at the bottom of the page.

Comment: `.dialog` isn't part of basic jQuery; you need jQuery-UI as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to include the applicable `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css`!

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SP8vM/2/):